# Integration script to support SOA

Tags: maven, ant

In our dev environment we do have couple of services that is dependent on each other, which need to be deployed before we use the system. What would be the best solution. I tried ANT which seems like not a good solution. Thinking to use Maven but not sure where to start. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Maven you can have the different services in different modules that and get them all packaged and deployed before you run a test suite or so. There is not much I can tell you in more detail apart from the fact that there are [free books](http://sonatype.com/Support/Books) around that should help you with Maven usage.

Of course you can also do all that with Ant or other build systems. However I would definitely at least suggest to use a dependency management system like Ivy if you opt for Ant.